# Is there any way to load all classes in a specific path without knowing their package names?

Tags: java, class, reflection, package, classloader

I'm writing a java app that do some operation on a text file. I'm going to add an ability in my app that can use the operation of users and operate them on file too. I forced them to implement my interface to hold their method names in my hand. And forced them to put their class files in a specific path to load them in my app but I don't have any idea to get their package names of user's classes to load them with method `class.forName(packageName.ClassName)`.

**Is there any way to load all classes in a specific path without knowing their package names??**

Answer (score 2):

The names of the classes are extracted from the JarEntry.

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(JarPath);
Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();

URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar+"!/") };
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
    if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
        continue;
    }
// -6 because of .class
String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
className = className.replace('/', '.');
Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the users to add a text file that lists all their class names at the top level of their class path. Then you can use `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` to get these files and get the class names.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The Java ClassLoader.loadClass(String) method requires that class names must be fully qualified by their package and class name (bb "binary name" in the Java Language Specification).

It is possible to load and reload classes at runtime in Java using Java Reflection. Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the Java virtual machine.

Dynamic Java Class loading is an important feature of the Java Virtual Machine because it provides the Java platform with the ability to install software components at run-time.

Loading a class dynamically is easy. All you need to do is to obtain a ClassLoader and call its loadClass() method. Here is an example:

```
public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args){

  ClassLoader classLoader = MainClass.class.getClassLoader();

  try {
       Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.jenkov.MyClass");
       System.out.println("aClass.getName() = " + aClass.getName());
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you said right, but my problem is to find "com.jenkov" before load the class.

Comment: the next method is to load all classes from a jar file.